# Support for HTML in Description field in MS Dynamics 2011 custom activity

Tags: dynamics-crm, customization, dynamics-crm-2011

When I have created a custom activity, how do i configure the descriptionfield to support html?

Like the descriptionfield that is used in an email activity.

Answer (score 1):

The description field of all activities, except the email activity, is plain text. This field gets rendered as text field.

You could try to convert the content of the filed dynamically into html, but keep in mind that this is not covered by the public api.